# I believe this is a bug in clang++ related to the access to a class's public member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, public, clang++

The following [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99fdd4f58779d6e8) in clang:

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "f()\n"; }

struct S {
    typedef void(*p)();
    operator p() { return f; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.operator p()();
}
```

Yields:

> ```
> main.cpp:13:16: error: unknown type name 'p'; did you mean 'S::p'?
>     s.operator p()();
>                ^
>                S::p
>
> main.cpp:6:19: note: 'S::p' declared here
>     typedef void(*p)();
>                   ^
> ```

But it should, as the expression `s.operator p()()` accesses a public member function of the object `S::s`. Am I missing something?

If I'm wrong, I would appreciate a quote from the Standard supporting the answer.

Comment: Your link said it all: *"did you mean 'S::p'?"*

Comment: Please paste the compiler errors into the question, don't just link to them.

Comment: Name lookup for conversion operators uses type-matching rather than lexical (character) matching. Lookup would have succeeded even if you said `s.operator decltype(&f)()()`

Comment: This code looks well-formed though, because the spec says "If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its conversion-type-id is first looked up in the class of the object expression and the name, if found, is used.". So this really smells like a bug in clang...

Comment: The issue here is whether `p` should first be looked up in class scope or not. gcc and clang differ.

Comment: [CWG 1111](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1111)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Clang.  I believe the code is correct.

Clang 4.0.0 reports:

```
<source>:13:16: error: unknown type name 'p'; did you mean 'S::p'?
    s.operator p()();
           ^
```

However, from C++14 3.4.5/7 [basic.lookup.classref]

> If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its conversion-type-id is first looked up in the class of the
>   object expression and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire
>   postfix-expression. In each of these lookups, only names that denote types or templates whose specializations
>   are types are considered.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A { };
> namespace N {
> struct A {
>     void g() { }
>     template <class T> operator T();
> };
> }
>
>
> int main() {
>     N::A a;
>     a.operator A();
>        // calls N::A::operator N::A
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

In your example, the type `p` should have been found in the class without requiring qualification.

Comment: After further analysis, I don't think I really understood the reason for the sentence `Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression` in [basic.lookup.classref]/7. Note that the example shown [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f827434ffe43e3b), can't compile. Could you show an example where the sentence above would be of any use?

Comment: In that example, the type-name `A` is correctly looked up in the context of `N::A`, giving the injected-class-name which means `N::A`.  The fact that you don't have any such operator in the accessed object is a separate error.

Comment: Here is an example where name lookup in the scope of the class type fails, but name lookup in the scope of the entire postfix-expression succeeds: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fa9ae6e5f261edc  In the call `b.operator A();`, there is no name `A` from the scope of `N::B`, but `M::A` can be found from the scope of calling function `M::f`.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for your comment. I finally came to the conclusion that the example in the link shows the use of a name lookup in the scope of the entire postfix-expression.